# Generic Averaging - need a Generic Type but have an int instead

Tags: java, arrays, generics, math, arraylist

I'm trying to implement an abstract generic average class.  It must have a concrete method for averaging.  How does one get around the problem of division, dividing the number of elements (which is always an integer) by the sum of the array or array list?  I'm using an array here.  Using an array list has the same issue.  It appears I must supply the array size but I really should not have to.

EDIT:  The generic average class shall have three only methods where E is a generic type:  E add(E f, E s); E divide(E f, E s); and E setToZero().  There shall be one concrete class with a signature of E average(E[] array).  The numbers must be represented as objects of a class, like Integer and Double, not primitives int and double.  I think that changes the tenor of the question.  Thanks for the help so far.  I appreciate this forum. END_EDIT

With the above in mind, this code below compiles but is not what is required.  I believe I've done my due diligence without success looking here.

EDIT2:  My customer (Java instructor) said he was fine with int as the second argument and had no problem with adding another method to the class.  I do not think the problem was defined well in that is was over constrained and not intended to be.

```
public abstract class GenericAverage<E>
{
    private E sum;
    private E average;

    public GenericAverage()
    {
        sum     = setToZero();
        average = setToZero();
    }

    public E Average(E[] array, E size) // wrong, it must be "E Average(E[] array)"
    {
        //E thisSize = 0; // which of course won't work
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) // to get that array length as an E      {
            sum = add(sum, array[i]);
            //thisSize = thisSize + 1; //which will not work
        }
        average = divide(sum, size);
        //average = divide(sum, getSize(array));  // maybe this is the answer I seek?  
        return average;
    }

    public abstract E add(E f, E s);
    public abstract E divide(E f, E s);
    public abstract E setToZero();
    //public abstract E getSize(E[] f);  // maybe this is the way to the answer?
}
```

Comment: Your class should probably have a method `abstract E divide(E f, int n)`

Comment: You already know, that you can use `array.length` to get the size, but you think that the method `Average` needs the array size as the second argument? I don't get it.

Comment: I need the divisor (the denominator) to be E, not int.  So "abstract E divide(E f, int n)" is not the requirement.  It must be E, not int.  I think using the getSize method I commented out is the right way.  I need to test that out though.

Comment: What is you use case? Because if you are want an average that is most likely a double, is it not?

Comment: The average will be any number type to include Rationals.  In my case, I am using integers (int), floats (float and double), and rationals (I have a rational number class).

Comment: `E` should be a subtype of `Number` and dividing double (for example) through integer works. So `abstract E divide(E f, int n)` should be ok.

Comment: It sounds like you have very precise requirements. It might help if you posted them.

Comment: The generic average class shall; have three methods with these extact signatures:  

E add(E f, E s);
E divide(E f, E s);
E setToZero();

There shall be a concrete method with this signature:
E average(E [] array)

The numbers are represented as objects of a class; Integer, Double.

Hmm...this last requirement may be my problem.  I've been thinking in terms of primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's been a suggestion to use `array.length` and change the signature of `divide` to take an `int` for the second argument.

If it is important for `divide` to take arguments of type `E`, consider adding a method

```
public abstract E fromInt(int f);
```

and using that to convert the length to `E`.

That method could also replace `setToZero()`, or at least be used in a default implementation.

---

In the interest of code reuse, consider moving `add()`, `divide()`, etc. to a separate class, `Calculator<E>`. An instance of `Calculator` would then be given to `GenericAverage` on creation.

You may even want to move `average()` to the `Calculator` class.

Comment: I used this very method.  My customer (ok, my Java instructor) told me int is fine as the second argument in place of E.  I don't think you can create the class he wanted without added this fromInt method.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this works for Integer, Long, Float and Double.

```
public abstract class AbstractAverage<E> {

    private E sum;
    private E average;

    public AbstractAverage() {
        sum = setToZero();
        average = setToZero();
    }

    public E average(E[] array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            sum = add(sum, array[i]);
        }
        average = divide(sum, array.length);
        return average;
    }

    public abstract E add(E f, E s);
    public abstract E divide(E f, int s);
    public abstract E setToZero();
}
```

If you absolutely want the second parameter of divide to be of type E, then store the class type of the generic `E` in the constructor and cast your variable to it. That is however ugly, and achieves nothing, really.

However this `divide` method may be reasonable, as was suggested in the comments.

```
public abstract E divide(E f, Number s);
```

Comment: `<T extends Number> E divide(E f, T s);` can be just `E divide(E f, Number s);`